# Why does db2 timestampdiff return error SYSFUN:07?

Tags: db2, db2-zos

Given a query like this one:

```sql
select timestampdiff(4, char(ORDER_DT - ORDER_DT)) as TEST
from mytable;
```

Using IBM DB2 z/OS 12 with IDAA, you may get this error:

```
ROUTINE SYSFUN.TIMESTAMPDIFF (SPECIFIC NAME TIMESTAMPDIFF) 
HAS RETURNED AN ERROR SQLSTATE WITH DIAGNOSTIC TEXT SYSFUN:07.
SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=38552.
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the `char` cast may return a leading space, so the timestampdiff argument will be something like `' 00000000000000.000000'`.  This argument will return the `SYSFUN:07` error in certain circumstances.

The fix is to cast to `char(22)`:

```sql
select timestampdiff(4, cast(ORDER_DT - ORDER_DT as char(22))) as TEST
from mytable;
```